# Why does the for of loop doesnt works with splice

Tags: javascript

I want to return a string after removing a certain given alphabet. In this case I want to remove every 'p' from 'apple'.
This is the code Ive written, it only removes the first 'p' and not the second 'p'. However if I enter the string as 'aplpe' it works fines and gives me the right answer 'ale'.

```
function removeChar(str, char) {
    let arr = str.split('');
    for (let x of arr) {
        if (x === char) {
            arr.splice(arr.indexOf(x), 1);
            console.log(arr);
        }
    }
    let word = arr.join('');

    console.log(word); //prints 'aple'
}

removeChar('apple', 'p');
```

Please tell me why 'apple' gives the wrong answer and 'aplpe' gives the right. (I tried running with 'appple' and it returns 'aple', however if I run with four 'p',  like 'apppple' it returns the new string as 'apple'. Notice how it fails to delete 'p' every continuous even increase in number of 'p' in the original string.

I think the for of loop bugs out because we are modifying the original array while the for of loop works but I cant figure out what exactly is happening.

Comment: You shouldn't modify an array as you iterate over it. When you delete the first `p` everything after it shifts left "apple" -> "aple" but the iterator has already done the character at index 1 ("p") so it moves on to index 2 ("l").

Comment: Would not be easier  to use `indexOf` and `substring` or just replace char with empty  string ?

Comment: Or just `"apple".replaceAll('p', '')` -> "ale"

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you modify the array while traversing it. The different examples you have tried have hinted this. Here are the cases:

- when you are using apple here are the runs of the for loop and which characters you take. You can see that after removing the first 'p' the for loop moves to the next character, but since the array has changed (i.e. all characters have "moved" left), the next character is 'l' and not the second 'p':

  - ***a***pple (character is not p so skip)
  - a***p***ple (character is p so remove it, but the array becomes *aple*)
  - ap***l***e (character is not p so skip)
  - apl***e*** (character is not p so skip)
- In your other example it works in similar fashion, it still skips characters but it seems it is working correctly because p-s are not together

  - ***a***pple (character is not p so skip)
  - a***p***lpe (character is p so remove, but the array becomes alpe)
  - al***p***e (character is p so remove, but the array becomes ale)

The suggestion here is just to use:

- `'apple'.replace(/p/, '');` - this replaces only the first occurrence of 'p'
- `'apple'.replace(/p/g, '');` - this replaces every occurrence of 'p'

Have in mind that `replace()` does not modify the string so you must assign it to a variable.

Another suggestion is to check the documentation and see how [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) work

Comment: That explains the strange behavior, thanks a lot. Further, I noticed that when you iterate the array from the last to the beginning the splice method works just fine, as moving from the end to the beginning doesnt mess up the indexes of the element that are yet to be iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

This way is so much easier

```js
function removeChar(str, char) {
  let newStr = str.split(char).join('');
  console.log(newStr);
}

removeChar('apple', 'p');
```